# Drawing LyX tables

Tags: tables, lyx

How can I draw this table in LyX?

[image]

Comment: You may read the fine Manual or look at https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert --> Table...
```

Set the number of columns (10) and rows (4).

Select the first row and click on the icon to remove the bottom border (or select the second row and click on the icon to remove the top border), you'll find it at the bottom of the page.

In the second row, select the cells from the 3rd to the last and remove the left border, the same for the third and 4th rows.

In the 4th row select the cells from the second to the last and remove the top border.

[image]

Now select a column at a time, right click with the mouse choose settings and set the desired width (I have the Italian version, I'm not sure about the correct English name of the commands):

[image]

Select the cells you would like to join in the 2nd row and click on `multicolumn` in the table setting. The same for the 3rd and 4th column.

To have a cell which is both `multicolum` and `multirow` you need some ERT.
First of all in your `Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble` add these rows:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{4.9cm}
\addtolength{\mylength}{16\tabcolsep}
```

`\usepackage{multirow}` loads the `multirow` package, `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}` is not necessary but improves the look of your table, the other instructions create a new length in these way: `4.9cm` = sum of the width of all the columns included in your `multicolumn` plus `16\tabcolsep` = sum of width of all the column separators included in your `multicolum`:

[image]

Then in the 3rd row multicolumn you have to write this in ERT (with `CTRL L`):

```
\multirow{2}{\mylength}{\centering\rule{0pt}{10pt} One cell (some text to show that this is a multicolum and multirow cell)}
```

I've added also some `\rule{0pt}{10pt}` to improve the look of your cells:

[image]

This is my `.lyx` file (you can copy it and create a `yourfile.lyx`, which you can open in LyX as an example):

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{4.9cm}
\addtolength{\mylength}{16\tabcolsep}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="4" columns="10">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="middle" width="2cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.5cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.6cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.5cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.6cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.5cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.6cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.5cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.6cm">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0.5cm">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="1" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
rule{0pt}{10pt}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 One cell
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="1" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
multirow{2}{
\backslash
mylength}{
\backslash
centering
\backslash
rule{0pt}{10pt} One cell (some text to show that this is a multicolum and
 multirow cell)}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
rule{0pt}{10pt}
\end_layout

\end_inset

One cell
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="1" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

And this is the result:

[image]

For further info see the [LyX wiki page](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables) and the [multirow package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf).

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I want.
The big cell is supposed to be one cell and not many without borders

Comment: @Hatem I'm afraid that to have `multicolumn` and `multirow` at the same time you need some ERT. I'll edit my answer asap.

Comment: @Hatem See my updated answer and let me know if it is OK now, thank you!